# Jetpack Compose UI Test with Material3 DatePickerDialog

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-datepicker, datepickerdialog, gui-testing, android-jetpack-compose-material3

My question is pretty simple. How do I perform any selections on a DatePickerDialog in Jetpack compose's UI Tests?

Answer (score 1):

The M3 `DatePickerDialog` is built using compose unlike the M2 `DatePickerDialog`, so in order to test it, you need to know what the nodes look like. While the `DatePickerDialog` is active, you'll have multiple roots, so in order to get the node tree for the `DatePickerDialog`, you'll want to use `composeTestRule.onAllNodes(isRoot()).get(1).printToLog("T:")` to print out your node tree and examine how the `DatePickerDialog` works.

The dates within the date picker can be selected using `onNodeWithText`, though the actual text to match isn't just the day of the month as it appears in the dialog. Instead, you'll need to match dates written out such as `'Wednesday, November 15, 2023'`. This is easy enough to do using `DateTimeFormatter` using the pattern `EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy`, but be aware that the current date is also prefixed with 'Today' (Today, Thursday, November 16, 2023)

Other controls within the `DatePickerDialog` also respond to `onNodeWithText` such as the OK/Cancel buttons, or `onNodeWithContentDescription`, such as navigating the months or setting a year.

Answer (score 0):

For any Jetpack Compose widget that you're unfamiliar with you can print the node structure to logcat with the following command:

```
composeTestRule.onRoot().printToLog("ARBITRARY_LOG_TAG")
```

From that you should get something like this in logcat after running the test:

```
| Text = '[Tuesday, January 16, 2024]'
| Role = 'Button'
| Focused = 'false'
| Selected = 'false'
| Actions = [OnClick, RequestFocus]
| MergeDescendants = 'true'
|-Node #142 at (l=411.0, t=841.0, r=537.0, b=967.0)px
| Text = '[Today, Wednesday, January 17, 2024]'
| Role = 'Button'
| Focused = 'false'
| Selected = 'false'
| Actions = [OnClick, RequestFocus]
| MergeDescendants = 'true'
|-Node #145 at (l=537.0, t=841.0, r=663.0, b=967.0)px
| Text = '[Thursday, January 18, 2024]'
| Role = 'Button'
| Focused = 'false'
| Selected = 'false'
| Actions = [OnClick, RequestFocus]
| MergeDescendants = 'true'
|-Node #148 at (l=663.0, t=841.0, r=789.0, b=967.0)px
```

You can then interact with those DatePicker elements by clicking on them, i.e.

```
composeTestRule.onNodeWithText("Tuesday, January 16, 2024").performClick()
```